# Can BLE iOS device be peripheral and central at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, peripherals, cbcentralmanager

Is there any possibility to have both peripheral and central mode available at the same time?
In that case we are advertising as peripheral while listening for advertisements of other devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - You can 
Althpough the same device being central and peribheral at the same time is not standard as pe Bluetooth current specification, iOS currently supports it

Comment: thanks a lot. I found the answer to this in CoreBluetooth videos as well.