# Is it possible to operate in both central and peripheral modes without 1309?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-bluetooth

#### Short Version

Anybody aware of a CB iOS application which operates in both central and peripheral modes, and in its role as central, connects to peripherals?  An actual application or a sketch in a repository somewhere would be great.

#### Longer

Operating in both modes has been broached on SO before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599784/can-ble-ios-device-be-peripheral-and-central-at-the-same-time)), and `Unknown Error: 1309` in `didFailToConnectPeripheral` has been mentioned ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380561/ios-corebluetoothwarning-unknown-error-1309)).

Extensive experiments operating in both modes, as well as a conversation with an Apple employee about a TSI opened have convinced me that connecting to a peripheral in an application which is using both central and peripheral modes will result in a 1309, which has a very high probability of reoccurring on subsequent connections to that peripheral (until the device is rebooted).

Apple said this was due to a deadlock caused when using both modes, though I have been extremely careful about partitioning calls to `CBCentralManager` vs. `CBPeripheralManager`, and ensuring their activities do not overlap.

Given that the bug is not mentioned very often at all, I'm somewhat curious about whether other people have managed to avoid it, or are just not interested in this use case.

Comment: Did you ever solve your 1309 issue? Or find some resources to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's one hundred percent possible, and actually pretty straightforward. Just don't run both on the main thread. I've released several applications that use both and I've never personally encountered that error.

And if you did receive the `didFailToConnect:`, just save the `UUID` (identifier now) of the peripheral, retrieve the peripheral again, and call connect. Good to go.

Also side note, it's good practice to only advertise the peripheralManager when need be. If you need it to constantly advertise then you'll still be good to go. But if you can avoid it, just advertise when you need to. I've seen a little extra sluggishness when advertising for long periods (while also doing cbcentral work).

Comment: The 1309 happens when operating in this way in bluetooth-central & bluetooth-peripheral background modes.  Have you done that?  The 1309 reoccurs for a given peripheral up to 100% of the time after it first happens, so explicitly reconnecting is not helpful - it'll just happen again.

Comment: Would have been clearer about the background stuff in the description, but I clarified this when doing some more testing today.  The 1309 can happen in the foreground, but only during the lifecycle of an application which was at one point backgrounded while performing central/periph. tasks.